# Comparing JSONFields in Django

Tags: django, django-models

If two models both have JSONFields, is there a way to match one against the other? Say I have two models:

```
Crabadoodle(Model):
  classification = CharField()
  metadata = JSONField()

Glibotz(Model):
  rating = IntegerField()
  metadata = JSONField()
```

If I have a Crabadoodle and want to fetch all the Glibotz objects with identical metadata fields, how would I go about that? If I know specific contents, I can filter simple enough, but how do you go about matching on the whole field?

Answer (score 0):

There is no implementation of this in Django but it is possible by  [performing raw query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/) using [jsonb operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE)(@>,<@)

Something in line of following

```
select * 
from someapp_crabdoodle crab 
join someapp_glizbotz  glib 
on crab.metadata @> glib.metadata and crab.metadata <@ glib.metadata 
where crab.id = 1
```